# Decorators in VSCode doc comments get formatted wrong

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, comments, documentation, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to write documentation comments with code examples to my application in VSCode and I noticed that decorators show up in the tooltip all weird. It seems that some formatting is applied due to the @ symbol but I cant find a way to escape it. My code and code example is in TypeScript.

Heres an example of the issue:

[image: Example of a badly formatted tooltip]

This is what was in the doc comment (the missing backtick on line 7 is intentional to make the example render properly here, in real code there was 3 backticks):

````
/**
 * Decorator to mark a class as injectable  
 * **Example:**
```ts
@injectable()
class TheThing {}
``
 */
export const injectable = inversify.injectable
````

Thanks!

Comment: Having a similar issue with webstorm. Does anyone have a solution to this yet?